# Load image on fragment, android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, crash

I'm a very beginner as android developer and I wanted to build a mockup app for my assignment. I was able to program the app and get it working, but when I installed it on my phone, it crashes everytime I want to load a new section/fragment.

I conclude that the crash is due to **excessive uses of image from drawable folder**, which causes the crash due to the high resource requirement. so I needed to load image using assets folder instead.

But until now, I haven't figured out a way to load image from assets folder on fragment. *findViewById, inputstream*, all resulted in an unknown method error.

Anyone's help would be gladly appreciated.

*Source code and APK can be found here:* https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1_AQxgFWCzuT0Vxdkx0cmxQMG8?usp=sharing

Comment: What error you are getting ? can you share the logcat please ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam here you go. [Logcat File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1_AQxgFWCzuWjVGR1lWNjRTcTA/view?usp=sharing).

curiously i also got a warning `I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` when clicking on button. the apps is very laggy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're loading large images into ImageViews, you should be using an image loading library. I would recommend Glide: https://github.com/bumptech/glide (there are instructions on how to include Glide in your project, and how to use it on the Github page).

Loading your images in this way should solve the issue of poor performance, however you should also be careful about storing lots of high resolution images in your project, as it can increase the size of your app by a lot.

In order to use *findViewById* in a fragment you should use the *onCreateView* method like so (I'm using an ImageView in my example):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view); 

    return view;
}
```

As far as I am aware, there would be no advantage to using the assets folder over the drawable folder.

Comment: Thanks for the help! i'll try it now to see if it works